# How to properly combine ARC code with NON ARC code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I know that there are questions about that and I read them. I need `XML` parser in `iOS`. I need to use `GDataXML` parser. I disable ARC for it but in the examples there are also NON ARC commands like `retain` and `release`.

I will remove them, but can this lead to some memory leaks? I suppose not, but I am not sure.

Comment: If you disable ARC for the file, why would you remove calls to `release` and `retain`?

Comment: No @rmaddy. I disable arc for the parser. But in the example of how to use is, there are still NON ARC commands which I will remove. I am wondering if this can lead to memory leaks or other problems. In general people say that ARC + NON ARC is ok.

Comment: OK, so `GDataXML` is MRC code and you disabled ARC for those files. Fine. You can use `GDataXML` with either ARC code or MRC code. It doesn't matter.

Comment: 10x, for the info @rmaddy.

Comment: As an additional information: Most of the naming rules and other definitions that ARC applies are only for compatibility to MRC. ARC itself needs almost nothing of them.

Comment: The problem will go away if you stop thinking about `retain` and `release` and start thinking about object ownership and how it works in MRC and in ARC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this can't lead memory leaks. Just use **-fno-objc-arc** for NON ARC files.

"Automatic Reference Counting implements automatic memory management for Objective-C objects and blocks, freeing the programmer from the need to explicitly insert retains and releases. It does not provide a cycle collector; users must explicitly manage the lifetime of their objects, breaking cycles manually or with weak or unsafe references.

ARC may be explicitly enabled with the compiler flag -fobjc-arc. It may also be explicitly disabled with the compiler flag -fno-objc-arc. The last of these two flags appearing on the compile line “wins”."

See the [clang docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) for more details.